# Remove pin lock from an old forgotten phone

Tags: lock-screens

I broke my current phone so I thought that I would use my old Samsung j1(2016) but it seems that I forgot the 10 digit pin code (10 because the code used all digits including 0). I searched the net but the phone doesn't have developer option activated, custom rom/recovery and wifi/3g deactivated. 
Please help me I don't want to delete all my data.

Answer (score 0):

You can Unlock your device using Odin to flash firmware but it can't stop get formatted during flash process.
When flashing a firmware it clear the internal storage.